# convert lines to auto shapes using FreeHandDrawing

Tags: c#, .net

I can draw shapes with using **FreeHandDrawing** which have black border as below. But i would like to convert them to auto shapes which have red borders as below.

[image]

Do you suggest any start guide for making this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It sounds like the use of Hough Transforms can help best-fit those shapes to the hand-drawn ones